# Oneplus two cannot be found

Tags: usb, phone, adb

I recently got a oneplus Two. When I plug it into my computer (running ubuntu 16.04), it is not found at all. I have come across a bunch of fixes that say that a filesystem containing windows and mac drivers should come up. I do not get the drivers. I have tried all of the fixes that I have, and none of them work. The charges when plugged in, and I have tried it with and without usb debugging on with it set to mtp, and in fastboot mode as well. Nothing will find it. Please help.

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f3:21d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0c45:64cb Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What's the output you get? Did you try sudo?

Comment: I get no output from adb devices and fastboot devices

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `lsusb` while the phone is on and connected in MTP mode.

Comment: What version of Android is your phone using?